R: Replicating an INDEX MATCH to the Corresponding Column
The operation I want to achieve is similar to an Excel-style INDEX MATCH. Essentially, I have a frame:
dta <- read_excel('CPI/Global Inflation New.xlsm',
                  sheet = 'Cleaned', skip = 1)
colnames(dta)[1] <- 'Date'
dta$Date <- as.Date(dta$Date, format='%d%m%Y')

That looks like this:
    |  Date          US    Canada      EU    Germany
---------------------------------------------------
1   |  2023-03-15    3.1      2.8     0.9       1.3
2   |  2023-04-15    3.3      2.5     1.2       1.5
3   |  2023-05-15    3.2      2.6     1.0       1.4
.
45  |  2024-04-15    2.9      2.7     2.1       2.1
46  |  2024-05-15    NA       2.6     NA        2.3


And I want to create a new frame which has the country headers as one column, and the most recent value for that country in the second column. For example:
    | Country    Latest
-----------------------------
1   | US         2.9
2   | Canada     2.6
3   | EU         2.1

That 'new frame' so far is:
new_frm <- data.frame(colnames(dta[, -1]))
colnames(new_frm)[1] <- 'Country'
new_frm <- cbind(new_frm, "Latest"=NA)

I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract the relevant values from the dta frame. In Excel I would just pass the country name as a lookup value to the MATCH function, and then return the corresponding value (perhaps for the three most recent dates). Replicating this is R has proven more challenging... not really sure how to go about this. Any advice would be appreciated.

You can get the data in long format, drop the NA values and get the corresponding value for the latest date available for that country/region.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dta %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = "Country", values_to = "Latest", 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(Latest = Latest[which.max(Date)], .by = Country)

#  Country Latest
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 US         2.9
#2 Canada     2.6
#3 EU         2.1
#4 Germany    2.3


An example using unpopular choices: reshape() and by() from base.
# X := your data
reshape(transform(X, Date = as.Date(Date)), 
        direction = "long",
        varying = i<-names(X)[-1L],
        v.names = "Value",
        idvar = "Date",
        timevar = "Country",
        times = i) |>
  by(~Country, \(x) with(na.omit(x), Value[which.max(Date)])) |>
  array2DF()

giving
  Country Value
1  Canada   2.6
2      EU   2.1
3 Germany   2.3
4      US   2.9

You might want to introduce a rule for NA's.
